# ActionScript and XML: Pull in a linked image

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I need to add a new variable in our xml file to pull in a linked image icon

Here is the current actionscript:

```
stop ();
//
var xmlLoaded:Boolean = false;
//var xmlurl:String = "xml/flagFile.xml";

var xmlurl:String = "http://nstpr.com/sites/wd40/facebook/iframe/global/flagfile.xml";


//var xmlurl:String = "http://nextwavemultimedia.com/nstpr/GoGlobal/xml/flagFile.xml";
var xmlFile:XML = new XML ();
xmlFile.ignoreWhite = true;
function loadXML ()
{
    thumbArray = new Array ();
    bigArray = new Array ();
    txtArray = new Array ();
    linkArray = new Array ();
    xmlFile.load (xmlurl);
    tracevar.text = "xmlurl = " + xmlurl;
    xmlFile.onLoad = function (success)
    {
        //trace ("success = " + success);
        tracevar.text += "\n success = " + success;
        if (success)
        {
            parseXML (this.firstChild);
            //trace ("xmlFile = " + xmlFile.firstChild);
            tracevar.text += "\n xmlFile.firstChild = " + xmlFile + " :: " + this;
            delete loaderFill_mc.onEnterFrame;
            childLength = xmlFile.firstChild.childNodes.length - 1;
            tracevar.text += "\n childLength = " + childLength;
            if (childLength > 0)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i <= childLength; i++)
                {
                    linkArray[i] = new Array ();
                    bigArray.push (xmlFile.firstChild.childNodes[i].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
                    thumbArray.push (xmlFile.firstChild.childNodes[i].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue);
                    txtArray.push (xmlFile.firstChild.childNodes[i].childNodes[2].firstChild.nodeValue);
                    var link_length:Number = xmlFile.firstChild.childNodes[i].childNodes[3].childNodes.length;
                    tracevar.text += "\n link_length = " + link_length;
                    if (link_length > 0)
                    {
                        for (var j = 0; j < link_length; j++)
                        {
                            linkArray[i][j] = xmlFile.firstChild.childNodes[i].childNodes[3].childNodes[j].firstChild.nodeValue;
                        }
                    }
                }
                xmlLoaded = true;
            }
        }
    };
}
loadXML ();
```

And here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Server SYSTEM "opt/pdos/etc/pdoslrd.dtd">
<text>

    <flag>
        <big>https://nstpr.com/sites/wd40/facebook/iframe/global/biggerImages/unitedKingdom.png</big>
        <thumb>https://nstpr.com/sites/wd40/facebook/iframe/global/flagimages/unitedKingdom.png</thumb>

        <text>United Kingdom</text>
        <links>
            <link><![CDATA[<font color='#000000'><a href='http://www.wd40.co.uk/?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social_media&utm_campaign=Global' target='_blank'><u>www.wd40.co.uk</u></a></font>]]></link>
            <link><![CDATA[<font color='#000000'><a href='http://www.facebook.com/OriginalWD40.UK?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social_media&utm_campaign=Global' target='_blank'><u>Facebook</u></a></font>]]></link>
            <link><![CDATA[<font color='#000000'><a href='http://www.twitter.com/OriginalWD40_UK?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social_media&utm_campaign=Global' target='_blank'><u>Twitter</u></a></font>]]></link>
        </links>
    </flag>             

</text>
```

Basically, I just need to be able to add an image within the < link > so instead of linking the word Facebook, it would link an image of a Facebook symbol.  When I add the image path in there though, the link does work but the image itself does not appear, it is just blank where the image should be.

I tried this:

```
<link><![CDATA[<a href='http://www.facebook.com/OriginalWD40.UK?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social_media&utm_campaign=Global' target='_blank'><img src="http://nstpr.com/sites/wd40/facebook/iframe/global/images/icon-facebook.png" alt="" /></a>]]></link>
```

But, that did not work... the image did not appear

My apologies if this is very easy but i'm not an actionscript guy.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can send the new xml content to a server side script ( php, asp, ... ) which can update the file on the server.

Comment: @akmozo update which file on the server? the output is a .swf file that pulls in the .xml info – i believe the new variable needs to be added into the actionscript before it will read from the .xml file but not sure how to properly set that up

Comment: Are you updating your xml file manually ?

Comment: @akmozo Yeah, I'm updating it manually to define the links and the images, etc.

Comment: OK, I see, so you are trying to put an image instead of a simple text, but you didn't get it ! But to show image, I think that your `TextField` should be multiline.

Comment: @akmozo correct, what i tried was this: <link><![CDATA[<font color='#000000'><a href='http://www.facebook.com/OriginalWD40.UK?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social_media&utm_campaign=Global' target='_blank'><img src="http://nstpr.com/sites/wd40/facebook/iframe/global/images/icon-facebook.png" alt="" /></a></font>]]></link>      – but, that did not work; the image did not appear

Comment: Your text field should be multiline, your html code should be correct and clean, and all unnecessary html code should be removed because flash is not a browser.

Comment: @akmozo well the code is correct (i edited my question above so you can see) so that's not the issue. not sure how multiline would affect anything either. if you have an example of what that would look like i could give it a shot. but this is more general advice not necessarily a solution to the question

Comment: I wasn't speaking generally, it was the solution of your question. I put an answer, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

According to Adobe [about the **`<img>`** tag](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000305.html) to work into a [html text of a text field in AS2](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000306.html) :

> The  tag lets you embed external image files (JPEG, GIF, PNG), SWF files, and movie clips inside text fields and TextArea component instances. Text automatically flows around images you embed in text fields or components. **To use this tag, you must set your dynamic or input text field to be multiline and to wrap text**.

And

> **To create a multiline text field with word wrapping, do one of the following :**
>
> - In the Flash authoring environment, select a text field on the Stage and then, in the Property inspector, select Multiline from the Text Type menu.
> - For a text field created at runtime with createTextField (MovieClip.createTextField method), set the new text field instance's multiline (TextField.multiline property) and wordwrap (TextField.wordwrap property) properties to true.

So to get your html code working, **you should use a multiline with wordwrap enabled text field**. You can also insert some text ( even a space ) before your `<img>` tag, you will get it working.

Hope that can help.